# How to set a path for the source file to be used in my c# .net project after the setup?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

Is there a way to prompt the user to set a path once after the setup of the application is completed?

I have done a project in C#.NET where my database file is an Excel workbook. Since the location of the connection string is hard coded in my coding, there is no problem for installing it in my system. When it comes to the other systems, the location will not match.. Is there a way to set the path initially after the setup so that all users can use it in different systems?

Comment: Do you store your connection string in App.config? Show us it, you may use relative connection string if your database is in your root directory

Comment: No i don't store it in App.config..

I store it it like:
con1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=//01hw149391/Mold Automation/EIS_Marketing.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
            con1.Open();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that store your ConnectionString in App.config file. Like as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
     <add name="DefaultUniqueName" connectionString="Connection String"
      providerName="Provider Name" />
     <add name="UserDefine" connectionString="Connection String"
      providerName="Provider Name" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

On start up project ask user to choose Connection string option: 1) Default or 2) Select New File

If User select new file then update UserDefine connectionstring.

**UPDATE CONNECTION STRING (VB.NET)**

```
Dim oAppConfig = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

oAppConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("UserDefine").ConnectionString = "FilePath"
 oAppConfig.Save(Configuration.ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal)
```

**C#**

```
System.Configuration.Configuration oAppConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

oAppConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("UserDefine").ConnectionString = "FilePath";
oAppConfig.Save(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ask at the start of the program. If the user supplies a value or select 'default' then set a registry or temp file or some other flag and use this remind yourself next time if you need to ask.

```
using System.IO;
.
.
... Main...

if(!File.Exists("user_has_toldme_already")){
   ... ask the user
   File.WriteAllText("user_has_toldme_already","dummy text");
   .
   . Set the value of my connectionstring (you could even record  it in the file above
   . and load it when you need it
}

.
. rest of code
.
```

Comment: thank you so much for your quick reply... can you please brief it because iam a little new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a configuration file to your project.

[Codelicious](http://generally.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/using-appconfig-for-user-defined-runtime-parameters/) explains how to do it.

- add an app.config file
- add some settings to that file, e.g.

  ```
  <appSettings>
      <add key="OperatorName" value="Rita"></add>
      <add key="LoggerLevel" value="5"></add>
  </appSettings>
  ```
- access the settings using the `ConfigurationManager` class.

This site - [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/store-connection-string-in-web-config) - explains how to do this for connection strings. Choose which is best for you.